# How can I get an array out of a select optgroups and options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I want an object with this format

```
    var optgroups = [
    {
      name: "Cat1",
      options: [
        { text: "item1", value: "1" },
        { text: "item4", value: "4" },
      ],
    },
    { name: "Cat2", options: [{ text: "item2", value: "2" }] },
    { name: "Cat3", options: [{ text: "item3", value: "3" }] },
    ];
```

And I want to create it based on what's already populated in a select element in a form

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Cat1">
      <option value="1">item1</option>
      <option value="4">item4</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Cat2">
      <option value="2">item2</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Cat3">
      <option value="3">item3</option>
   </optgroup>
 </select>
```

What JavaScript code (jQuery is also an option) would achieve such an object?

This is an old code base so things like React/Vue are not an option.

Comment: Just loop through the HTML elements.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212), use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor), [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) and [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the `<optgroup>` elements to loop over and use it again to find all the options.

```js
const optgroups = [];
document.querySelectorAll("#mySelect > optgroup").forEach(group=>{
  const obj = {name: group.label, options: []};
  group.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(option=>{
    obj.options.push({text: option.textContent, value: option.value});
  });
  optgroups.push(obj);
});
console.log(optgroups);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <optgroup label="Cat1">
    <option value="1">item1</option>
    <option value="4">item4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cat2">
    <option value="2">item2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cat3">
    <option value="3">item3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up using thanks to [@hev1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/hev1)

```
  const optgroups = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll("#mySelect > optgroup"),
  ].map((group) => ({
    name: group.label,
    options: [...group.querySelectorAll("option")].map((opt) => ({
      text: opt.textContent,
      value: opt.value,
    })),
  }));
```